# Making a simplified and less repetitive version of this jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I have got a few jquery functions which I notice I'm repeating quite a bit of code...

For example:

```
function booking() {
    $('#shade').fadeIn(function(){

      // show booking box

    });
}

function subscribe() {
    $('#shade').fadeIn(function(){

       // show subscribe box

    });
}
```

What I'm curious about learning is optimising this a bit. Say the return function:

```
$('#shade').fadeIn(function(){});
```

Is it possible I could write a less wordy version of this? It turns out I'm wrapping a lot of things in this code many times so I would like to know how to put this into my own function with a return so I could simply do something like:

```
shade(function(){

    // show booking

});
```

How does this work? Or is there an even more optimal way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.

```
function shade(callback) {
   $('#shade').fadeIn(callback);
}
```